# when pushing docker image to private docker registry, having trouble marking it 'public' via my script (but can do via web ui)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am pushing a docker image to a private docker registry, and am having trouble marking it 'public' via 
a script.

For this discussion, I'm guessing the content of the Dockerfile doesn't matter... so lets assume I have the following in my 
current working directory:

*Dockerfile*

```
from ubuntu
touch  /tmp/foo
```

I build like this:

```
docker build -t my.private.docker.registry.com/foo/jdk1.8.on.ubuntu14.04  .
```

Then, I am doing my push like this:

```
docker push my.private.docker.registry.com/foo/jdk1.8.on.ubuntu14.04
```

Next, I navigate  to the web site that allows me to manage my private registry (@ the url http://my.private.docker.registry.com)
I look at my image, and I see it has a padlock icon next to it, indicating that it is private.  I can manually unlock from the 
web UI, but I'd like to know if there are any options to docker's  'push command that will allow me to mark the image
as 'public' without manual intervention.

One thing I tried was setting global settings for my namespace such that all new repos would be readable/writable by all users.
Specifically: I went into the Docker web ui for my private registry and for the namespace 'foo' I tried adding default permissions
(for any newly created repos) such that all users will have 'write' access to any new repo pushed under the 'foo' namespace.

However, even after doing the above, when I pushed a new image to my private registry under namespace foo, that image was still 
marked with the pad-lock.  I looked up the command line options for 'docker push', and I did not see any option that looked like 
it would affect the visibility of the image at the time of push.

thanks in advance for your help !
 -chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to the folks who manage the Docker registry at the company I'm at now:  there is no command line way to enable permissions for users other than the repository creator to have write access to that repo.   You have to go to the web UI and manually mark the repo 'public', and you have to add permissions for each user  (although it is possible to have groups of users, and then add a whole group  -- this still is clunky because new employees have to be manually added to the group).

I find it hard to believe that there's no command line way.. But this is what our experts say..   If there are other experts out there who have a better idea, please chime in !   Otherwise I will do it manually through the web UI (grrrrRRrr).